# Java Lambda expression parameters

Tags: lambda, java-8

I'm trying the understand the following method reference code using Lambda expressions in Java:

```
interface MyFunc<T> {

    boolean func(T v1, T v2);
}

class HighTemp {

    private int hTemp;

    HighTemp(int ht) {
        hTemp = ht;
    }

    boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
    }

    boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp < ht2.hTemp;
    }
}

class InstanceMethWithObjectRefDemo {

    static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc<T> f, T v) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            if (f.func(vals[i], v)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count;

        HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = {new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82),
            new HighTemp(90), new HighTemp(89),
            new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(91),
            new HighTemp(84), new HighTemp(83)};

        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp,
                new HighTemp(89));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a high of 89");

        HighTemp[] weekDayHighs2 = {new HighTemp(32), new HighTemp(12),
            new HighTemp(24), new HighTemp(19),
            new HighTemp(18), new HighTemp(12),
            new HighTemp(-1), new HighTemp(13)};

        count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::sameTemp,
                new HighTemp(12));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a high of 12");

        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::lessThanTemp,
                new HighTemp(89));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a high less than 89");

        count = counter(weekDayHighs2, HighTemp::lessThanTemp,
                new HighTemp(19));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a high of less than 19");
    }
}
```

My question is, why function sameTemp has just one parameter? The interface declare sthat it must have 2 parameters, so make no sense for me. Maybe the hTemp instance variable is enough for both? I took this from Java the complete reference book and there the author explains this:

> Blockquote
>
> In the program, notice that HighTemp has two instance methods: `sameTemp( )` and
>   `lessThanTemp( )`. The first returns true if two HighTemp objects contain the same
>   temperature. The second returns true if the temperature of the invoking object is less than
>   that of the passed object. Each method has a parameter of type HighTemp and each methoreturns a boolean result. Thus, each is compatible with the MyFunc functional interface
>   because the invoking object type can be mapped to the first parameter of `func( )` and the
>   argument mapped to `func( )`’s second parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855138/how-does-a-method-reference-to-an-instance-method-of-an-arbitrary-object-of-a-p and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139725/using-method-reference-instead-of-multi-argument-lambda and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516331/whats-the-difference-between-instance-method-reference-types-in-java-8 (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037015/why-stringbuilderappend-is-biconsumerstringbuilder-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What many people overlook when doing OO programming is ... how that is really implemented. Assume:

```
class C {
  public int foo(int parm) { return parm; }
```

The point is: the idea of calling a method "on" an object is an *abstraction*. How would you implement that in assembler; so that a CPU can actually execute that code. You realize: "calling on" isnt possible there. On that level, you only call functions somewhere in memory. But how would a function know about its owning object?!

Leading to something that few people know - you can write the above code  as:

```
class C {
  public int foo(C this, int i) {
        System.out.println("i: " + i);
        return i;
   }
}
```

To be on the safe side, I also wrote a little test in eclipse for that:

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    assertThat(new C().foo(5), is(5));
}
```

Runs fine in my eclipse, unit test passes, and prints "i: 5".

So, the whole secret is: when defining **methods** on an object, there is always an (normally invisible) first argument "this" given to that method!

Thus: although your methods look like taking only one parameter, the "missing" parameter is the object on which you are calling the method!

And in that sense: `boolean func(T v1, T v2)` asks for **two** parameters of type T. And both methods, like `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2)` ... can be written as `boolean sameTemp(HighTemp this, HighTemp ht2)`; et voila: two parameters of type T.