# Java: Using "this" as an argument/parameter name of an instance method?

Tags: java, methods, language-lawyer

Recently [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39531677/3102935) I have learned that the following appears to be legal java:

```
class Bar {
    void foo(Bar this) {}
}
```

Now, I have tried to find where in the java standard it says that you are allowed to do this, and looked [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) but I couldn't find the section.

Can someone quote where it allows this form of method declaration and what the restrictions of declaring an argument named `this` are?

Comment: Thats cool. Since I knew I tried to figure that "JLS" background; but my initial lazy attempts failed. And thanks to you, I now know!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is valid with 1.8 or above JDK versions.

And here is the [JLS saying that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1-220)

> The receiver parameter is an optional syntactic device for an instance method or an inner class's constructor. For an instance method, the receiver parameter represents the object for which the method is invoked. For an inner class's constructor, the receiver parameter represents the immediately enclosing instance of the newly constructed object. Either way, the receiver parameter exists solely to allow the type of the represented object to be denoted in source code, so that the type may be annotated.

If you read full bullet points you find the below imp notes,

> Where a receiver parameter is allowed, its type and name are specified as follows:

- **In an instance method, the type of the receiver parameter must be the
  class or interface in which the method is declared, and the name of
  the receiver parameter must be this; otherwise, a compile-time error
  occurs.**
- **In an inner class's constructor, the type of the receiver parameter
  must be the class or interface which is the immediately enclosing
  type declaration of the inner class, and the name of the receiver
  parameter must be Identifier . this where Identifier is the simple
  name of the class or interface which is the immediately enclosing
  type declaration of the inner class; otherwise, a compile-time error
  occurs.**

Comment: Huh... what was the reason for this change? It feels a bit unnecessary to be able to name a parameter 'this'

Comment: @Gikkman The last sentence explains why: *the receiver parameter exists solely to allow the type of the represented object to be denoted in source code, **so that the type may be annotated**.* Though I think it really means: so that the (implicit) *parameter* may be annotated.

Comment: I've read your edit like 5 times and I still don't get it. Guess I found something I need to look up further here, thanks :-)

Comment: I would have found it useful if the `this` could have been generic (bounded by the enclosing class type), it seems that isn't possible

Comment: @Gikkman - for example, consider if you're using the "checker" frameworks's [map key checker annotations](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#map-key-checker) to ensure your map references are valid at compile time you could have a method `String lookMeUp(@KeyFor("map") MyClass this) { return map.get(this); }` and it would only allow you to call the method if the object you're calling it on is known to be a valid key for the given map.